# Xcode Tableview prototype cell stepper updates every 8th cell

Tags: ios, swift2, uitableview

**Xcode 7.3.1 Swift 2.2**

I have 2 files Scene2ViewController.swift and customecell1.swift

**This is cell1 in storyboard**

[image: cell1]

**This is my IBAction for the Stepper:**

```
@IBAction func pcStepper(sender: UIStepper)
{
    
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath!
    
    let button = sender
  
        if let superview = button.superview
        {
            if let cell1 = superview.superview as? customeCell1
            {
                indexPath = tableview1.indexPathForCell(cell1)
                
                cell1.pcSoldLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
//pcSoldLabel is the first zero on the prototype cell
            }

     productArray[indexPath.row].pcOrders = Int(sender.value)

}
```

**This is the table populate function:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let cell1 = self.tableview1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1",   forIndexPath:
 indexPath) as! customeCell1

     cell1.productLabel.text = productArray[indexPath.row].productName

     return cell1 
}
```

**The problem is if we call this image stepper 1, then we count 1,2...8 steppers down the table then the 8th stepper is updated to the same value as the 1st, and this pattern repeats itself all the way down the table even though I have only intentionally updated the 1st. Its seems the stepper sender.value is being repeated when generating the 8th cell**

**Also if I scroll sufficiently 'down' the table, the pcOrderLabel (the zero) and the stepper are reset as if I never used it**

**ALL VARS ARE WEAK**

**On-a-side, this value is going into an array and the array updates as desired**

Comment: Cells get reused. You need to update all properties of every cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: could you provide more details or a link that illustrates how to 'update all properties' thanks

Comment: You need to update the cell's labels and the stepper and any other UI components present in your cell.